# XML increase specific values with number

Tags: xml, addition

I am a noob if it comes to XML and/or Python, so this may be a stupid question. I can't find any answers on the internet...

So I have an XML file which is used in a game engine (GTA 5) but i need to increase all Z-values (Those are the vertical coördinates in 3D space) because my own map object spawns too low, down in the sea. All my z-coördinates should be increased with 153,433 for it to spawn above sea level. Problem is, i have a few hundred of these z-coördinates, and they are all different... So if I would do it manually it would take some time.

Is there a way, to add (in this case) 153,433 to ALL of the z-coördinates? A friend thought Python might do the trick but he doesn't know much about it.

Here an example, where z = 21,2429:

```
<Item type="CEntityDef">
  <archetypeName>OBJECT</archetypeName>
  <position x="-3033,01" y="-7256,72" z="21,2429" />
  <rotation x="0,0" y="0,0" z="0,0" w="1,0" />
  <scaleXY value="1" />
  <scaleZ value="1" />
</Item>
```

Now, I would have to get 21,2429 and add 153,433 to it. But on other objects, the z-value is totally different from 21,2429...

This may be a kind of weird question, but I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Do you know Python, XSLT, or any other programming languages?  If so, [edit]  your question, add your attempt, state where you're stuck, and we'll happily help.  If not, this is good motivation to learn some programming on a simple task, but you won't learn by just asking for code without trying to produce it first yourself.  This site closes such questions as being too broad.

Comment: Alright, i got it, thanks! I'm starting to learn Python but i am not far enough into it to know how to solve this. Thanks for the answer!